# Javascript not working with HTML external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Notepad++, and I know for sure that it works when linking different files to the main HTML file.Here is the HTML code I'm using:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="style/css" href="adventure.css"></link>
    <script src="adventure.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick=log("testing")>Click Me</button>
    <div id="box">
        <div id="out"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is the JavaScript code:

```
function Gid(id) {
return getElementById(id);
}
function log(s) {
    Gid("out").innerHTML = s + "<br>" +
    Gid("out").innerHTML;
}
```

And the CSS for the divs

```
#box {
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    border:5px solid black;
    overflow:auto;
}
#out {
    width:500px;
}
```

Please help me figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Have you checked console for errors? Do you really use jQuery, or this tag is irrelevant?

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById(id);` not `getElementById(id);`

Comment: Please also change `<button onclick=log("testing")>` to `<button onclick="log('testing')">` to provide valid HTML delimiting :)

Comment: Define "not working."  How does it fail?  When you debug this in the browser, where does it fail?  Are there any errors on the JavaScript console?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie even though it works without it, it is good idea indeed. Nevertheless, I will still insist that inline JS is outdated.

Comment: @Regent... and I would agree with you. That is one of many changes I would make :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call function on onclick event as :

> onclick="log('testing')"

and you have to also use

> return document.getElementById(id);

in Gid function

that's it.

Comment: This was enough to get it to work, thanks! (I played around with it a bit, and it worked even without " " around log("testing"), the only problem was document.getElementById(id);

Answer (score 1):

The problems have been covered in comment and other answers.

As you tagged this question with `jQuery` here is the simpler jQuery equivalent:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <button id="testme">Click Me</button>
    <div id="box">
        <div id="out"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Code:**

```
// Listen for click on the id="testme" button
$('#testme').click(function(){
     // $('#out') is a jquery wrapped version of the id="out" div
     var $out = $('#out');
     // jQuery html reads/or writes innerHTML depending on parameters
     $out.html("testing" + "<br/>" + $out.html()); 
});
```

If the script precedes the elements it accesses in the page, you  will need to wrap it in a DOM ready handler:

```
$(function(){
    // Listen for click on the id="testme" button
    $('#testme').click(function(){
         // $('#out') is a jquery wrapped version of the id="out" div
         var $out = $('#out');
         // jQuery html reads/or writes innerHTML depending on parameters
         $out.html("testing" + "<br/>" + $out.html()); 
    });
});
```

Note: `$(function(){});` is just a handy shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

There are two updates that you need to do. First, replace this line:

```
<button onclick=log("testing");>Click Me</button>
```

with this line:

```
<button onclick="log('testing'); return false;">Click Me</button>
```

This should prevent your page from posting back when you click the button. Then replace this line:

```
return getElementById(id);
```

with this line:

```
return document.getElementById(id);
```

because you don't have any valid context there.

Comment: `return false` is quite useless here, but the whole idea is correct.

Comment: If the button is inside a form, then it will post data to the server. This is why I added the `return false;` bit.

Comment: I understood why you added it, but I don't see any `<form>`s in OP code. It's good to mention `return false` for preventing default behaviour in forms, I totally agree, but as additional note, not as part of _necessary_ "replace this with that"

Answer (score -2):

try to call the function onclick="log('testing')" like this it might work

Comment: That is an invalid HTML attribute. You can't nest double-quote inside double-quotes in an HTML attribute.

Comment: @Satpal... it "should" be `onclick="log('testing')"` as HTML attributes are preferred to have double-quotes.

Comment: @DharmuImmannavar what about `document.getElementById(id);` instead of `getElementById(id);`?

Comment: actually u have to do like this document.getElementById(id).

Comment: He means put that in your answer... not just a comment.